# Targeting phase not propogating event

Tags: javascript

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained) it says that during the target phase, the browser checks if the target property has an event registered to it, and if not it gets propogated to its parent. How come then when `div2`, which does not have an event handler, is clicked, the targeting phase does not propogate the click event to `div1` which has a click handler?

```js
      const evtPhaestr = [
        "NONE: ",
        "CAPTURING_PHASE: ",
        "AT_TARGET: ",
        "BUBBLING_PHASE: ",
      ];

      const logElement = document.getElementById("log");

      function log(msg) {
        logElement.innerHTML += `<p>${msg}<p>`;
      }

      function phase(evt) {
        log(evtPhaestr[evt.eventPhase] + this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim());
        console.log(evt.bubbles);
      }

      const div1 = document.getElementById("1");
      div1.addEventListener("click", phase);
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;

  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover {
  border: 1px solid #faa;
  background: #fdd;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      1
      <div id="2">
        2
        <div id="3">
          3
          <div id="4">
            4
            <div id="5">5</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">clear output</button>
    <section id="log"></section>
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me it propagates, div1 run listener on bubbling phase.

Comment: I see it propagating, both in Firefox and Chrome. It displays `BUBBLING_PHASE: 1`, that it is consistent both with the description of eventPhase and with `this` (that is currentTarget, not target).

Comment: @Dima Vak Yes, it is propogating in the bubbling phase, not the target phase, sorry for not being clear. My question is why is it no propogating in the target phase

Comment: @JaimeBlázquez If you could also help out

Comment: As I understand it, the capture phase is the event going down until it reaches the target, the target phase is just the event firing at the target, and the bubbling phase is the event going up. So, if it is not the target itself, it is not the target phase, it is the bubbling phase. In my opinion, the second bullet in the link should say something like "Then, if bubbles is true, it passes to the next phase, bubbling".

Comment: @JaimeBlázquez Yes that makes sense! Follow-up question. Say I have a button nested in a div. The div has an event listener. I click the button. Where does the div's event handler get the event object from? Is there some propogation thingo that happens or is it just that the browser passes in an event object to every handler that gets called.

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer about fine details, sorry. The `div` gets the event if it has registered an event *and* a previous event listener has not stopped the propagation (see [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) ). Regarding if the event object is the same object or a different one for each handler, I really don't know, I've never written code that depends on it. I thing it is the same object, but not really sure, and doing a quick search I can't find anything backing that opinion.